# Setup Facebook login with HWIOAuthBundle, symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, hwioauthbundle, symfony-3.1

I'm using HWIOAuthBundle to setup a facebook login but while I'm running the path :
 http://localhost:8000/connect or
http://localhost:8000/connect/check-facebook

he failed to load the page with no error msg just a web browser error

> :ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

routing.yml

```
api:
  resource: '.'
  type:     'api_platform'

app:
  resource: '@AppBundle/Action/'
  type:     'annotation'

api_login_check:
  path: /api/login_check



hwi_oauth_redirect:
  resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/redirect.xml"
  prefix:   /connect

hwi_oauth_connect:
  resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/connect.xml"
  prefix:   /connect

hwi_oauth_login:
  resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/login.xml"
  prefix:   /connect

facebook_login:
  path: /connect/check-facebook



fos_user_security:
  resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"

fos_user_profile:
  resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/profile.xml"
  prefix: /profile

fos_user_register:
  resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/registration.xml"
  prefix: /account/register

fos_user_resetting:
  resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/resetting.xml"
  prefix: /resetting

fos_user_change_password:
  resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/change_password.xml"
  prefix: /profile

fos_user:
  resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"
```

security.yml

```
security:
encoders:
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_READER: ROLE_USER
    ROLE_ADMIN: ROLE_READER

providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email

firewalls:
    login:
        pattern:  ^/login
        stateless: true
        anonymous: true
        provider: fos_userbundle
        form_login:
            check_path: /login_check
            username_parameter: _username
            password_parameter: _password
            success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
            failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
            require_previous_session: false

    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_token_id: form.csrf_provider
            login_path: /login
            check_path: /login_check

            # if you are using Symfony < 2.8, use the following config instead:
            # csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
        oauth:
            resource_owners:
                facebook:           "/connect/check-facebook"
            login_path:        /connect
            use_forward:       false
            failure_path:      /connect
            default_target_path: /
            oauth_user_provider:
                service: hwi_oauth.user.provider.fosub_bridge
        lexik_jwt: ~
        logout:     
            path: /logout  
            target: /login
        anonymous:    true
        stateless: true

    # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false


access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/books, roles: [ ROLE_READER ] }
    - { path: ^/, roles: [ ROLE_READER ] }
    - { path: ^/logout, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

config.yml

```
imports:
- { resource: parameters.yml }
- { resource: security.yml }
- { resource: services.yml }

# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed 
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#application-related-configuration
parameters:
    locale: en

framework:
  #esi:             ~
  translator:      { fallbacks: ["%locale%"] }
  secret:          "%secret%"
  router:
    resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
    strict_requirements: ~
  form:            ~
  csrf_protection: ~
  validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
  serializer:      { enable_annotations: true }
  templating:
      engines: ['twig']
  default_locale:  "%locale%"
  trusted_hosts:   ~
  trusted_proxies: ~
  session:
      # http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#handler-id
      handler_id:  session.handler.native_file
      save_path:   "%kernel.root_dir%/../var/sessions/%kernel.environment%"
  fragments:       ~
  http_method_override: true
  assets: ~
  php_errors:
      log: true

  # Twig Configuration
twig:
  debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
  strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"

 # Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
  dbal:
      driver:   pdo_mysql
      host:     "%database_host%"
      port:     "%database_port%"
      dbname:   "%database_name%"
      user:     "%database_user%"
      password: "%database_password%"
      charset:  UTF8
      # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
      #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
      #     e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
      #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
      #   3. Uncomment next line:
      #     path:     "%database_path%"

  orm:
      auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
      naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
      auto_mapping: true

   # Swiftmailer Configuration
  swiftmailer:
     transport: "%mailer_transport%"
     host:      "%mailer_host%"
     username:  "%mailer_user%"
     password:  "%mailer_password%"
     spool:     { type: memory }

   # Nelmio CORS
  nelmio_cors:
     defaults:
     allow_origin:   ["%cors_allow_origin%"]
     allow_methods:  ["POST", "PUT", "GET", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"]
     allow_headers:  ["content-type", "authorization"]
     expose_headers: ["link"]
     max_age:        3600
  paths:
     '^/': ~

 fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: AppBundle\Entity\User
    use_username_form_type: false

 lexik_jwt_authentication:
    private_key_path: '%jwt_private_key_path%'
    public_key_path:  '%jwt_public_key_path%'
    pass_phrase:      '%jwt_key_pass_phrase%'
    token_ttl:        '%jwt_token_ttl%'

 hwi_oauth:
    connect:
       confirmation: true
       registration_form: fos_user.registration.form.factory
    firewall_names: [main]
    fosub:
        username_iterations: 30
        properties:
            facebook: facebookID
    resource_owners:
        # Facebook Access
        facebook:
            type:                facebook
            client_id: '%oauth.facebook.id%'
            client_secret: '%oauth.facebook.secret%'
            scope:               "email"
            options:
                display: popup
                csrf: true
```

Comment: Ran into a similar issue with work in the past that maybe related. Chrome doesnt seem to like redirects to/from `http` to `https` connections. This resulted in a loop and ultimately Chrome giving too many redirects error.

Comment: Still not working

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure is this the cause of the issue, but at a first look I think you forgot to [configure the OAuth Firewall](https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/3-configuring_the_security_layer.md#b-configure-the-oauth-firewall) to make the `/connect` and `/connect/check-facebook` routes accessible by anonymous users.

So you should add in your `security.yml`:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/connect, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/connect/check-facebook, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

To prevent unexpected conflict, it's also recommended to "import" all OAuth routes at the very first place in your `app/config/routing.yml`:

> To prevent strange issues, this route should be imported before your
>   custom ones.

Comment: Always the same problem

Comment: @Achraf after the changes I suppose you've cleared the cache right? If yes you should take a look at the server log files and at the symfony profiler to see to which route you are redirected after `/connect` and `/connect/check-facebook`.